# nested repeater in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater, nested-repeater

```
A
    a1
    a2
    a3
B
    b1
C
    c1
    c2
```

How can I do that using nested repeaters? I have a category and a sub-category. But sub-category count is not stable. It depens on it's category. It can be any number 1 to 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article seems to achieve the very same thing.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6140/A-quick-guide-to-using-nested-repeaters-in-ASP-NET

Instead of querying an XML file, you can query a DB or any dataset you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with code-behind - 
add to each repeater HiddenField and put the id within.
on prerender, foreach repeater - set the correct select command.